# Route 53 to add my IP with specific port number

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have deployed my flask app in the ec2 instance and assigned an elastic IP for it. As flask app runs on port no: 5000. I want to add this IP address to Route 53 but it is giving me an error:

My app IP address: http://13.126.68.99:5000

Bad request.

```
(InvalidChangeBatch 400: ARRDATAIllegalIPv4Address (Value is not a valid IPv4 address) encountered with '13.126.68.99:5000'')
```

Answer (score 3):

Route53 is a dns resolver and it **doesn't apply to ports**.  It must point to IP address, without port. So you can't do what you want. Port management is done on the instance itself, or your load balancer.